# Messages no longer sends images on macOS

Tags: macos, messages, bug

My Messages app on macOS (Sonoma) has stopped sending images. Any image I send, using any method (drag and drop, copy paste, etc.) fails to arrive for any participant on a Messages thread. I get no feedback that anything is amiss on my end.

How do I get Messages to start delivering images again?

Comment: Have you tried on different WiFi networks? Does it work on other devices (if available)?

Comment: @Thinkr No problems sending from iOS devices on the same network. And why should the network suddenly have issues (without any feedback)?

Comment: Ok. I actually got the same problem a few weeks ago but it got fixed when I changed network. I think it was due to the network being set to block too important amounts of data being transferred. I'm sorry, I don't know what to do in your case, I hope someone finds an answer soon.